# Trying Python 3 code for this simple Employee object and I'm stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the simple python 3 object code from the web that is not platform dependent.. I cannot get working
class Employee:

```
def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.pay = pay
    self.email = first + '.' + last + '@company.com'

def fullname(self):
    return '{}{}'.format(self.first, self.last)

emp_1 = Employee('John','Doe','80000')
emp_2 = Employee('Jane','Foo','90000')

emp_2.fullname()
print (Employee.fullname(emp_1))
print (emp_2.fullname())

The error I get is as follows:
```

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 class Employee:
>       2 
>       3     def **init**(self, first, last, pay):
>       4         self.first = first
>       5         self.last = last
>
> in Employee()
>       10         return '{}{}'.format(self.first, self.last)
>       11 
>   ---> 12     emp_1 = Employee('John','Doe','80000')
>       13     emp_2 = Employee('Jane','Foo','90000')
>       14
>
> NameError: name 'Employee' is not defined

Comment: where is you class Employee?

Comment: Your indentation

Answer (score 3):

Indentation is crucial in Python. Try the below code.

Your class instances must be defined *outside* the class itself.  This is recognised by there being no indentation for definitions of `emp_1` and `emp_2`.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@company.com'

    def fullname(self):
        return '{}{}'.format(self.first, self.last)

emp_1 = Employee('John','Doe','80000')
emp_2 = Employee('Jane','Foo','90000')

emp_2.fullname()
print(Employee.fullname(emp_1))
print(emp_2.fullname())
```

Comment: 3 minutes and almost equally looking answers .... I didnt even see yours before i posted mine. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is simply an indentation error.
Python defines scopes like `classes`, `methods` and other blocks by indentation. Usually 4 spaces are used.

Since you put your instantiation of `emp_1` and `emp_2` with the same indentation as the class's methods they are literally part of the class.

What you probably meant was:

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@company.com'

    def fullname(self):
        return '{}{}'.format(self.first, self.last)

emp_1 = Employee('John','Doe','80000')
emp_2 = Employee('Jane','Foo','90000')

emp_2.fullname()
print (Employee.fullname(emp_1))
print (emp_2.fullname())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@company.com'

    def fullname(self):
        return '{}{}'.format(self.first, self.last)

def main():
    emp_1 = Employee('John','Doe','80000')
    emp_2 = Employee('Jane','Foo','90000')

    emp_2.fullname()
    print (Employee.fullname(emp_1))
    print (emp_2.fullname())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please close this ticket